# Favorite new restaurant vs new favorite restaurant

Tags: meaning, adjectives, modifiers

> This is my *favorite new* restaurant.
> This is my *new favorite* restaurant.

Why is the meaning of these two different when you swap the adjectives?

Is it because favorite and new modify restaurant in the first one and favorite becomes a noun modifier where new modifies favorite meaning new favorite modifies restaurant in the second one?

I’m just confused because usually you can swap around adjectives without changing the meaning of the phrase but that is not the case here.

Answer (score 3):

In the first example, "favorite" is modifying "new restaurant," so it refers to your favorite among the new restaurants.

In the second example, "new" is modifying "favorite restaurant," so it refers to the most recent of your favorite restaurants (i.e. to the restaurant that has most recently become your favorite).

This is a good example of what Huddleston & Pullum (2002) call *stacked modification.* In your first example, "new" modifies "restaurant," and then "favorite" modifies "new restaurant." Instead of modifying the noun simultaneously, the adjectives modify the noun in sequence.

Comment: Do you happen to know why "my new favorite" has become much more productive than "my favorite new" since around 2000? https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=my+new+favorite%2Cmy+favorite+new&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3

Comment: @JK2 "My favorite new" is likely unpopular for semantic reasons. There aren't many cases in which you would say "my favorite of the new things"; "new" is usually too ambiguous to define a precise class from which you could select a favorite.

Comment: I'm not sure why "my new favorite" took off, though.

Comment: @JK2 The 3-grams do not cut out the false positives of the form 'This/He ... is my new favorite.'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Possibly. But this shows the same trend: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=new+favorite+restaurant%2Cfavorite+new+restaurant&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3

Comment: CGEL apparently borrowed the term 'stacked modifiers'; Edmond H. Weiss used the term in 1990, and the Council of Biology Editors (Committee on Graduate Training in Scientific Writing) as early as 1960.